# Print two space-separated integers

Tags: arrays

Meet Alex, a bright student who is dealing with an array challenge today. He has been given an array a1, a2, ..., aN of length N. The intriguing aspect of this challenge is that Alex can perform various operations on the array elements.

In a single operation, Alex is allowed to choose two indices l and r, where 1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ n. He can then multiply all the elements in the subarray [al, al+1, ..., ar] by -1, effectively reversing their signs.

Being pressed for time as he is running late for school, Alex is seeking your assistance in determining the maximum possible sum of numbers in the array. Additionally, he is eager to find out the minimum number of operations required to achieve this maximum sum.

Input Format
The first line contains an integer N, the length of the array.

The second line contains N space-separated integers a1, a2, ..., an, the array elements.

Constraints
1 ≤ N ≤ 2 * 10^5

-10^9 ≤ ai ≤ 10^9

Output Format
Print two space-separated integers: the maximum possible sum of integers in the array and the minimum number of operations required to achieve this sum.

Sample TestCase 1
Input
4
-1 0 -2 -1
Output
4 1
Explanation

We should select:

l = 0

r = 3

After one operation,

Array [0, 3] = { 1, 0, 2, 1}

The sum of the array = 1+0+2+1 = 4

Time Limit(X):
0.50 sec(s) for each input.
Memory Limit:
512 MB
Source Limit:
100 KB

If anyone knows how to solve it please share the code..There are 11 test cases only one is getting successful

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: And what does the title of teh question have to do with body of the question?

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
import random

n = 30
l = [random.randint(-9,9) for _ in range(n)]


sum_ = 0
operations = 0
prev_negative = False

for i in range(n):
    sum_ += abs(l[i])
    if (not prev_negative and l[i] < 0):
        prev_negative = True
        operations += 1
    elif (l[i] > 0):
        prev_negative = False


print(operations, sum_)
```

edit:

do your own input/output

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**